# How do I use environment variables in app.yaml file?

Tags: google-app-engine

For example, I stumbled upon this link https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/configuration/create-configuration-file which shows below in its examples (not particularly for env).

`resources:
- name: {{ env['name'] }}
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:`

Answer (score 2):

You **can only set** [environment variables in app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables) through the `app.yaml` and they can be accessed by your application instance.

> You can define environment variables in app.yaml to make them available to the app:
>
> ```
> env_variables:
> MY_VAR: 'my value'
> ```

access with `os.environ`

```
import os
os.environ.get('MY_VAR', 'default value')
```

---

The `app.yaml` file must be valid [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) and must follow the [app.yaml syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#syntax).

The example given isn't YAML. It's a jinja template file used to create a configuration file.

There might be simpler ways but here's a long shot: you can generate a valid `app.yaml` with the right environment variables (with their values) from a script.

- `template.jinja` - template to generate app.yaml
- `generate_app_yaml.py` - python script to generate app.yaml

Comment: Hi Jeff. You have got the question wrong. How do I use environment variables inside the YAML file? Perhaps you should remove/take your answer back.

Comment: MY_VAR: {{ env['MY_VAR_FROM_SHELL'] }}  ... if I want to create a more generic yaml file

Comment: I will give it a try soon. The approach looks promising. Thanks Jeffrey